# How to swipe to left and make slide move with the swipe gesture?

Tags: javascript, slider, swipe, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to add swipe gesture on Desktop devices. I figure out how to swipe to right but when I try to swipe to the left it's a problem. For some reason it detects moving to left but slide isn't moving with the mouse move. Can anyone help me with moving slide to left on mouse movement.
**Here is a demo:** [Slider with swipe gesture](https://jsfiddle.net/msak5de3/)

```
s.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  isDown = false;
  x = e.pageX - s.offsetLeft;
  s.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - move;
  if (Math.abs(move) > 200) {
     if (move < 0) {
        s.scrollLeft += move;
        nextSlide();
     } else {
        s.scrollLeft = 0;
        prevSlide();
     }
  } else {
     s.scrollLeft = 0;
  }
  move = 0;
  x = 0;
```

});

Comment: You need to explain what is wrong with your code.  Just saying "I can't do that" is the same as "it doesn't work".  Give some details if you want people to be able to help you.

Comment: @Archer I explain what's wrong in my code. Thanks for the tip.